# log4j2 is not writing to log file

Tags: log4j2

I am trying to use two loggers. one console log and a file log. the problem is that the fileLoGGER is not writing to file.

```
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <ApplicationInsightsAppender name="aiAppender">
        </ApplicationInsightsAppender>

        <!-- file appender -->
        <RollingFile name="LogToFile" fileName="..\standalone\log\app.log"
            filePattern="log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="fileLogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="consoleLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="aiAppender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="LogToFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger("consoleLogger");

```
private static final Logger fileLOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger("fileLogger");

fileLOGGER.debug("some string");
```

please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your configuration. You are using a relative path to your log file which means it will be relative to the current working directory - the directory where you started your application. So the file should be in a directory named standalone up one directory from that. However, it is possible log4j didn't have permission to that directory.

I would suggest you make sure you have

```
<Configuration status="debug" ..
```

specified so that you can see where log4j is creating your file.

Comment: Thank you very much Rogers. i think permission might be the problem because i created the file in JBOSS Server application logs directory.